# Use Fzero in BC function of pdepe with Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have to solve some parabolic PDE system with pdepe in Matlab.
is't possible and **secure** to call Fzero function inside boundary conditions function in Pdepe solver like this?

```
function [pl,ql,pr,qr] = pdex5bc(~,ul,~,ur,~)
kappa = nref*Dref*q/L;
jcell0 = 0;
k0 = 0.1; 
options = optimset('Display','iter'); % show iterations
jcell = fzero(@curOc,k0,options); % Call solver

pl = [jcell0 ; -1/(2*epsilonp)*jcell0/kappa ; 3/(2*epsilonp)*jcell0/kappa ;...
      jcell  ; -1/(2*epsilonp)*jcell/kappa ;  3/(2*epsilonp)*jcell/kappa];
ql = [kappa ; 1 ; 1 ; kappa ; 1 ; 1];
pr = [0 ; -1/(2*epsilonp)*jcell0/kappa ; 3/(2*epsilonp)*jcell0/kappa ;...
      0 ; -1/(2*epsilonp)*jcell/kappa ;  3/(2*epsilonp)*jcell/kappa];
qr = [1 ; 1 ; 1 ; 1 ; 1 ; 1];

    function F = curOc(z)
    deltaVint = (Rtco+Rext)*(Rp/(Rext+Rtco+Rp))*A*z*J0;
    Eta =  Pot+Vt/2*log(ur(2)/ur(3)^3)+Vt*log(ul(4)/Ncb)- deltaVint ;   
    F = z - (ur(5)/ur(2)*exp(beta*Eta/Vt)- ur(6)/ur(3)*exp(-(1-beta)*Eta/Vt));
    end 
end
```

**Let me expose my problem** : When I execute this code, following error occurs:

*Error using fzero (line 289)
FZERO cannot continue because user supplied function_handle ==>
pdeDSSC_new8bis/pdex5bc/curOc
 failed with the error below.
 User function 'pdeDSSC_new8bis/pdex5bc/curOc' returned a complex value
 when evaluated at 20;*
 *FZERO cannot continue.*

At some time integration of pdepe,fsolve returns a complex root. This happens when ul and ur become negatives.
Does someone can explain to me the problem?

Comment: What is your error? You've provided code, but it's not runnable on it's own. Is the function definition `curOc` nested within the function definition for `pdex5bc`? Are you sure you mean "nested" and not sub-function? If it really is a nested function, then you need to take special care of the variable that have scope in both the outer function and the inner one.

Comment: thank you Horchler for the remark. I didn't know the difference but my part of code looks like above after modification.